# Simulating exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck

Tags: simulation, stochastic-processes, monte-carlo

I am trying to simulate commodity prices using the exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck model from [Schwartz 1997](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1540-6261.1997.tb02721.x) p. 926 Equation (1). I am using the closed form solution from [Vega 2018](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s13662-018-1718-4) p. 5 Equation (9) which is:

$$\ln(X_{t})=\ln(X_{t-1})e^{-\theta \Delta t}+\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}{2\theta}\right)(1-e^{-\theta \Delta t})+\sigma\sqrt{\frac{1}{2\theta}(1-e^{-2\theta \Delta t})}\epsilon_i$$

Here is my code in Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(123)


def gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims):
    dt = float(T) / num_steps
    paths = np.zeros((num_steps + 1, num_sims), np.float64)
    paths[0] = X0
    for t in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        rand = np.random.standard_normal(num_sims)
        paths[t] = np.exp(np.log(paths[t-1]) * np.exp(-theta * dt) 
           + (mu - (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * (1 - np.exp(-theta * dt)) 
           + np.sqrt((1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * dt)) * (sigma ** 2) / (2 * theta)) * rand)
    return paths


X0 = 5
theta = 0.4
mu = 5
sigma = 0.15
T = 1
num_steps = 365
num_sims = 5

paths = gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims)
plt.plot(paths[:, :10])
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('time steps')
plt.ylabel('index level')
plt.show()
```

And here is the result I am getting:
[image: Simulation exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck]

This is not the result I expected, I expected the path to fluctuate around the long term mean $\mu$ and not a exponential rise.

**Question: Did I misunderstood the exponential Vasicek/Ornstein-Uhlenbeck meaning that this result is correct and expected or is there something wrong in my simulation?**

Comment: so what are you expecting us do?

Answer (score 0):

I used the formula from the Wiki page of Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_paths):
    dt = T / num_steps
    paths = np.ones((num_steps + 1, num_sims)) * X0
    for t in range(1, num_steps + 1):
        rand = np.random.standard_normal(num_paths)
        paths[t] = paths[t - 1] * np.exp(-theta * dt) + mu * (1 - np.exp(-theta * dt)) + sigma / np.sqrt(2 * theta) * np.sqrt(1 - np.exp(-2 * theta * dt)) * rand
    return paths


X0 = 5
theta = 0.4
mu = 5
sigma = 0.15
T = 1
num_steps = 365
num_sims = 5

paths = gen_paths(X0, theta, mu, sigma, T, num_steps, num_sims)
plt.plot(paths[:, :10])
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('time steps')
plt.ylabel('index level')
plt.show()
```

Results as follows

[image]